# TensorFlow regression with error :"could not convert string to float: "

Tags: python, tensorflow, non-linear-regression

**Problem:**

**ValueError: could not convert string to float:**

I have been sticking here for several days, and someone told me that Stack Overflow my solve my problem. This is the first time for me to ask question, so pleas forgive any possible mistakes.

The code is aimed to find relation between 15 inputs and 1 out put and ran under Jupyter. Data is extracted from 'data.xls' by using 'xlrd' and stored into list. I planned to represent the loss by calculating the mean squared error.

### **Thanks you !**

```
import xlrd
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf

book=xlrd.open_workbook('data.xls')
sheet0=book.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet_name=book.sheet_names()[0]

rows_number=sheet0.nrows

X=[]
for i in range(rows_number-1):
    temp=sheet0.row_values(i+1)
    del temp[0:4]
    X.append(temp)

Y=[]
for i in range(rows_number-1):
    temp=sheet0.row_values(i+1)
    Y.append([temp[3]])


w1= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([15, 10],name='matrix1', stddev=1))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[10]))
w2= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10, 10],name='matrix2', stddev=1))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[10]))
w3= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10, 1],name='matrix3', stddev=1))

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 15), name="x-input")
y_= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1), name='y-input')

a1= tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w1),b1)
a2=tf.add(tf.matmul(tf.nn.sigmoid(a1),w2),b2)
y=tf.matmul(tf.nn.sigmoid(a2),w3)
y=tf.nn.sigmoid(y)

loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_, y)
train=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)


    STEPS = 30000
    for i in range(STEPS):
        sess.run(train, feed_dict={x: X, y_: Y})
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-de3ef36f5080> in <module>()
      7     STEPS = 30000
      8     for i in range(STEPS):
----> 9         sess.run(train, feed_dict={x: X, y_: Y})
     10 
     11 

~\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1102             feed_handles[subfeed_t] = subfeed_val
   1103           else:
-> 1104             np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
   1105 
   1106           if (not is_tensor_handle_feed and

~\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    490 
    491     """
--> 492     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    493 
    494 

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

---

I have checked the data type of the elements of two list X and Y. And the shape is (835,15) for X, (835,1) for Y.

Here is the content of X and Y
[X-input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvMkK.png)[Y-input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdY2L.png)

Comment: This error means that the values of `X` and `Y` are not numbers. They are strings. Try converting them to numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much. But there is no quotation mark for each element if I print the list. Also, map(eval,X) seems unable to tackle it. I also find that it can run without error it replace the original code with sess.run(train, feed_dict={x: [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]], y_: [[0]]})

Comment: Screen shot was uploaded at the end

Comment: It worked because what you gave input was all numbers for sure. Most probably case is that there's one value in you `x` or `Y` which is either some english character or more likely it's empty. In other words there's one or more values which are empty. Try to find thm by using subsets of `X` and `Y`. To confirm my point, replace any of the `0's` in `feed_dict` with empty string`( ' ')`. It should give the same error.

Comment: wow, you are right. I went through those data and there were some empty cells. I deleted  empty rows, then no error. Thanks! O(∩_∩)O.

Comment: Please post answers as answers, not as updates to the question. This is to avoid confusion for future visitors. See [answer].

Comment: We have rolled back your edit in which you added your solution. Instead, post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When empty string(' ') is fed, it gives the error.**

---

The excel has several empty cells, so some values are empty and can not be converted into float. When empty string(' ') is fed, it gives the error.